# MySQL prepared statement not working when field has spaces

Tags: mysql, dynamic, prepared-statement

I am trying to create the following prepared statement that will output dynamic rows for a pivot table. My statement works if the 'Name' field has no spaces. However, when I add spaces to it (Project Strength Site Coordinator, for instance), I receive the following error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Strength Site Coordinator,MAX(IF(Name =
>   'TeenEatsSiteCoordinator', Name, NULL)) ' at line 1: PREPARE stmt FROM
>   @sql"

I have tried researching the issue and have not uncovered anything.

Here is a  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a30b4/1).

Thanks for any help you can give!

```
CREATE TABLE `Contacts` (
  `Contact_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `First_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Last_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

insert into Contacts values (1, 'John', 'Doe');
insert into Contacts values (2, 'Jane', 'Doe');

CREATE TABLE `Contact_Types` (
  `Contact_Type_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

insert into Contact_Types values (1, 'ProjectStrengthSiteCoordinator');
insert into Contact_Types values (2, 'TeenEatsSiteCoordinator');

CREATE TABLE `Contacts_Contact_Types` (
  `Contact_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Contact_Type_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);

insert into Contacts_Contact_Types values (1, 1);
insert into Contacts_Contact_Types values (1, 2);
insert into Contacts_Contact_Types values (2, 1);

SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(Name = ''',
      Name,
      ''', Name, NULL)) AS ',
      Name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from Contact_Types;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT c.First_Name, ', @sql, ' from Contacts c
left join Contacts_Contact_Types cct
  on c.Contact_Id = cct.Contact_Id
left join Contact_Types ct
  on cct.Contact_Type_Id = ct.Contact_Type_Id
group by c.Contact_Id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: You need to wrap field names with spaces in backticks.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I updated my code and wrapped the Name field within backticks. However, I am still receiving the same error. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape it in the `as` portion:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(Name = ''', Name, ''', Name, NULL)) AS `', Name, '`'
                                   )
                   ) INTO @sql
from Contact_Types;
```

Do note that `group_concat()` takes multiple arguments, so the nested `concat()` is, strictly speaking, unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Thanks for the feedback about `concat()` as well. I will get rid of it. Good day!